# On MouseDown event, change size of image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image that I need to change the size of at runtime, what I'm trying to do is that when a user press's the left mouse button and the cursor is on the border of the image then when he moves the mouse cursor the image size changes according to where the cursor is going.

This is what I have so far:

```
   Point p = e.GetPosition(this);
   Image img = (Image)e.Source;
   var pos =Mouse.GetPosition(this);


   if ((p.X == 89 && (p.Y > 204 && p.Y < 252)) || (p.Y == 245 && (p.X > 89 && p.X < 138)) || (p.Y == 213 && (p.X > 89 && p.X < 138)) || p.X == 138 && p.Y > 204 && p.Y < 252)
   {
       img.Width = p.X;
       img.Height = p.Y;
   }
```

The problem is that the image doesn't change according to the cursor.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your code's logic:
The image will change only on **very specific** coordinates. It took me quite a while to exactly click the image when `x == 138` for instance, and **even then** it took me more time to find the pixels that match `204 < y < 252`.

When I **did** find the correct locations, the image resized itself as requested.

I recommend rechecking the logic in your `if` statement and at the least - allow a bigger range of coordinates (for instance `x <= 40 && x >= 70` instead of just `x == 83`)

Comment: Blachshma - I changed the if statement you a were right, but still the picture doesnt change according to the cursor movment, it changes to a specific size, and i want to to change by the direction of the movment of the cursor, any ideas?

Comment: I'd use a mousedown event to record the first coordinates, then use the mouseup event to recorda second set of coordinates. Based on the difference of the x and y, you can find the direction and calculate a size acaccordingly